# Spring boot Jhipster image upload not working

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I wanted to upload image and some more stuff with form from angular. This is VM object :

```
public class UserPictureVM {

    private MultipartFile file;

    private String type;

    private String coverPosition;
```

And this is rest method :

```
 @PostMapping("/user/upload-picture")
 @Timed 
 public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadUserPicture(@RequestBody UserPictureVM userPicture){
```

This is Angular method that submit form :

```
saveCoverImage() {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('coverPosition', '0, 0');
    formData.append('file', this.coverForm.file);
    formData.append('type', 'cover');

    this.profileService.uploadImages(formData)
      .subscribe(res=> {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }
```

But i get error :

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting form with 3 request parameters. Because of that, you should change your controller method signature to this:

```
  public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadUserPicture(
      @RequestParam("coverPosition") String coverPosition,
      @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
      @RequestParam("type") String type)
```

Comment: I tried this but then file is parameter type : formData, and coverPosition and type are parameter type : query http://prntscr.com/ktfcfw